# Global variables in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, singleton, tdd

Ok, this subject is probably done to death but I wanted to throw it out there to see what people thought of my approach.

I need to create a simple WinForms application that will consist of a handle of forms. There will be variables that I can stick into the app.config as they'll never really change.  However there will be some variables that are pulled in from a database unique to the user thats logging in.  It's these variables that I need to persist and make available to the rest of the application to drive appropriate business logic.

Based on other articles on StackOverflow my plan would be to use the singleton pattern with IoC.  So first instantiating a class based on the singleton pattern which is hooked up to an interface.  The instantiated object would then be passed into the constructer of other methods in program.cs where I'll arrange most of my objects.  This should mean I can easily test and mock this and other classes (I think?).

I've seen there are two ways of creating a class based on the singleton pattern, one that is the 'classic' way of doing it but isn't thread safe.  The other requires slightly more coding but would be thread safe.  My WinForms project would be pretty simplistic and wouldn't require multiple operations running in the background.  Just simple CRUD operations fired off from the UI.  For ease, I thought I'd use the classic singleton (non-thread safe) approach.  That said, is that a bad thing to do, even for the most simplest of WinForm apps?

Comment: Since the WinForms UI thread is a single thread, I suggest the single threaded singleton would be appropriate, unless your application goes into multi-threaded territory.I realise WinForms and multi-thread are not incompatible and doing things on a background thread is a good way to make the UI 'snappier' but the axiom of "keep-it-simple" seems appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4.0+, just use [`Lazy<T>` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd64233129.aspx) for your singletons. If you insist on not caring about thread safety (why though?), `get => _value ?? (_value = GetValue())` is enough.

Comment: Thanks @squidward I didn’t know about Lazy<T> so will check it out and implement it in my project 